# Eclipse for Windows - using libPNG

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, libpng

I have to use the libPNG library in Eclipse for Windows in a C++ project.
The fact is I followed the tutorial http://wiki.openttd.org/Compiling_on_MinGW to install libPNG, and zlib before, obviously.
Now, Eclipse seems to find my `#include <png.h>` but when compiling the project, all references to the functions from libPNG send the error:

> Undefined reference to 'png_xxx'

I tried adding -lpng and -lz to the linker flags but I still get the errors.
Another thing is that during the build, the custom types from libPNG seem to compile, e.g. for example `png_structp png_ptr = NULL;` doesn't give any errors.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the post, fixed my error thanks to the addition of the libraries under: Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> MinGW C++ Linker -> Libraries -> Libraries (-l) -> add... "png" and "z". That's all, thanks !